# Formula to Assign whether a date is "In Business Hours" or "Outside Business Hours" in excel

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to create a formula to determine whether a phone call was made inside or outside of business hours based on the day and time of the call

Business hours are Monday to Friday 8AM to 8PM and Saturday 8AM to 2PM.

So essentially what I need to create the formula for is;

if call is Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and time is >8 and <20 or call is Saturday and time is >8 and <14 then show "Inside Business Hours"

For everything else show "Outside Business Hours"

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any testing solutions so that we can eliminate already tried solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dates are starting in cell `A2` , please enter this formula in cell `B2` and drag it to the bottom. your dates should be in this format `9/16/2017  1:05:00 PM`.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2,2)=7,"Outside of Business hours",IF(WEEKDAY(A2,2)=6,IF(AND(MOD(A2,1)<TIME(14,0,0),MOD(A2,1)>TIME(8,0,0)),"Inside Business Hours","Outside of Business Hours"),IF(AND(MOD(A2,1)<TIME(20,0,0),MOD(A2,1)>TIME(8,0,0)),"Inside Business Hours","Outside of Business Hours")))
```

Comment: It should work with that type also, just please check if dates are really formatted as date. (if you change formatting to general it should give you one big number,like 42992.234423)

Comment: Thank you, could you please vote as answered? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This formula should be sufficient:

`=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2)>1,MOD(A2,1)*24>=8,MOD(A2,1)*24<=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,14,20)),"In","Out")`

Answer (score 0):

These are the opening hours in the range D1:G8:
[image]

The date and time is in A2: `04.09.2017 20:00:00`

This is the formula:
`=IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);SECOND(A2)) > VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(A2);E$2:G$8;2;FALSE)/24;TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);SECOND(A2)) < VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(A2);E$2:G$8;3;FALSE)/24); "inside"; "outside")`

I hope I got the English names correct. This is my German original:

`=WENN(UND(ZEIT(STUNDE(A2);MINUTE(A2);SEKUNDE(A2)) > SVERWEIS(WOCHENTAG(A2);E$2:G$8;2;FALSCH)/24;ZEIT(STUNDE(A2);MINUTE(A2);SEKUNDE(A2)) < SVERWEIS(WOCHENTAG(A2);E$2:G$8;3;FALSCH)/24); "inside"; "outside")`

Comment: Why do you need minutes and seconds for this example? Seems like an overkill.

Comment: E.g. 20:10 is outside the business hours. Either you crop 20:10 to 20 (which needs an additional formula as well) or you go with the exact time. However, the exact time has the advantage that also crooked times like closing at 20:05 are possible. Using full hours only does not offer this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below formula.

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A1)>1,WEEKDAY(A1)<7),IF(AND(A1-INT(A1)>=TIMEVALUE("08:00 AM"),A1-INT(A1)<=TIMEVALUE("08:00 PM")),"Inside Business Hours","Outside Business Hours"),IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=7,IF(AND(A1-INT(A1)>=TIMEVALUE("08:00 AM"),A1-INT(A1)<=TIMEVALUE("02:00 PM")),"Inside Business Hours","Outside Business Hours"),"Outside Business Hours"))
```

See image for reference.

[image]

In the above formula,

- `WEEKDAY(A2)` will give day of the week (by default, it gives 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday)
- `A2-INT(A2)` will extract `Time` from the `DataTime` cell
- `TIMEVALUE("08:00 AM")` will give decimal number of the time in the string